# Product flat data “Cannot initialize indexer processor”

Tags: magento-1.9, database

I tried re-indexing with script reindexing.php file in root [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17641799/cannot-initialize-the-indexer-process/):

```
<?php
 require_once 'app/Mage.php';
 $app = Mage::app('admin');
 umask(0);
 for ($index = 1; $index <= 8; $index++) {
    $process = Mage::getModel('index/process')->load($index);
    $process->reindexAll();
}
?>
```

And on running this it shows me this error:
`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1118 Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 65535. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs' in /home/ccg/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228`

I First tried reindexing from backend which doesn't reindex `Product Flat Data` ? How to fix this issue, how to know the `1118 Row` ? and change the row type ?

Also, if i disabled product flat data, does that support for products while importing from CSV File ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229907/product-flat-table-will-not-reindex-row-size-too-large)

The key part from that issue:

This can be fixed by removing any attributes that you do not need to appear in the product flat data table by turning off the following attribute properties: Used in Product Listing and Used for Sorting in Product Listing and then attempting a reindex when you've reduced the character count to below the limit.

Comment: or alternatively not using flat product data, and implementing some full page caching to reduce load on the database.